# xcode выдает какие то логи в чем дело?

Tags: xcode, swift3

установил xcode 8 и первый же запуск (пустой абсолютно) выдает кучу логов (ошибок) как избавиться от этого

```
2016-09-14 13:57:19.611828 Lessons[13031:652032] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 13:57:19.616660 Lessons[13031:652032] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 13:57:19.644996 Lessons[13031:652029] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 13:57:19.703339 Lessons[13031:651974] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 13:57:19.751077 Lessons[13031:651974] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы это отключить в scheme поставьте OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не дало эффекта, : (

Comment: странно. у меня все работает как надо. давайте разбираться. убедитесь, что для правильного таргета поставили. посмотрите нет ли ошибок

Comment: я снял скрин все как у вас http://s011.radikal.ru/i315/1609/05/8a983d45270e.png

Comment: не disabled а disable

Comment: заработало, спасибо.